# Generate numbers /c /wpa2

Tags: c++, numbers

I want to generate 20 character wpa2 key, which consists of only numbers between 1- 10,000,000,000,000,000,000 in C++. Output format of each key must be in 20 characters format, like:

```
00000000000000000001
00000000000000000002
00000000000000000003
00000000000000000011
12300000000099945611
```

and so on.

I have this code, but:

1. It doesn't keep the numbers generated descending in 20 character format.

   ```
   for (int i=0;i<=10000000000000000000;i++){
       cout << 10000000000000000000 -i<<"\n";
   }
   ```
2. Those numbers r too big than(long) integer, so g++ compiler in linux shell also didn't want to execute, due to size of "10000000000000000000 -i".

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, why not just have a string, and increment the character at the lowest index, if it oveflows (> '9'), then increment the next character up. Repeat and rinse until finished.

So, something like this:

```
 std::string s = '000';

 std::string::size_type len = s.length()
 while (s != "999")
 {
    cout << s << endl;
    s[len-1] ++;
    int i = len-1; 
    while(s[i] > '9' && i >= 0)
    {
       s[i] = '0';
       i--;
       s[i]++;
    }
 }
```

However, if you have a machine that does one loop of the above code 1,000,000,000 times a second, it will take 317 years to run through your sequence. So I hope you have plenty of time and are eating healthily.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler needs to support 64-bit integers, if you want to store this as a number. It may be supported as long long data type. Change i to unsigned long long, and change the number literal to 10000000000000000000ULL. Be careful that you don't cast these values down to int (accidentally or otherwise) or you will lose some data.

Comment: This assumes the numbers don't go all the way to 19999999.... , which isn't clear from the OP's post - 12300000000099945611 is the largest shown, which is just over 63 bits. 19999999999999999999 is over 64 bits...

Answer (score 0):

Looping through all those numbers is going to take years, literally.

If you simply want to generate a random 20 character WPA2 key, you should do something like this instead using built in functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

std::string get_key() {
    // Define all allowed characters (a WPA2 key can also contain letters).
    std::string chars =
    "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    // Shuffle the characters.
    std::mt19937 g(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    std::shuffle(std::begin(chars), std::end(chars), g);

    // Return the first 20 characters.
    return chars.substr(0, 20);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << get_key() << std::endl;
}
```

If you only want a key consisting of numbers then remove all alpha characters from `chars`.

Comment: This doesn't solve the set problem - since it only generates ONE key. The task is to enumerate all possible keys (with digits).